# How to assign contents of List<String> to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, arraylist, richtextbox

I've tried this:

```
richTextBoxResults.Text = listStrSessionIdLines.ToString();
```

...but get the List's ToString() representation (I guess that's what it is: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]").

...and I've tried to try this:

```
listStrSessionIdLines.CopyTo(richTextBoxResults.Lines);
```

...but I get, "*Argument Exception was unhandled. Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.*"

Does this mean I have to assign the RichTextBox a number of lines first, or...???

Comment: one more tip I live by is when I need to call a method, eg `String.Format` I hover my mouse so that I can see what the method expects - `expects being the keyword`. Then say it wants a argument in the parameter thats of Type X, I declare type X and pass it in. Methods often have overloads, meaning that they can work with different parameters, so pressing up/down to scroll through them is also helpful in working out what is the most convenient in your situation. When you are passing in arguments to a method (in its parameter) type comma to refresh the tooltip indicating each arguments datatype.

Comment: `richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _List);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Most classes in the BCL have a ToString() method.`

When it comes to a `List Of strSessionIdLines` the ToString() tells you what type of object it is.

If you are casting for example an `int` to a `string` the `int.ToString()` will return its value, but if you do it on a array of integers `int[].ToString` it's `ToString()` method wont return eg a comma/linefeed separated string of values. As it appeared you expected.

> This is why assigning the .ToArray to the .Lines property of the
>   RichTextBox or a loop (or aggregate) to concatenate the List Of String
>   into one string to suit the .Text property of the RichTextBox works.

One more tip I live by is when I need to call a method, eg `String.Format` I hover my mouse so that I can see what the method expects - **expects**`being the keyword`. Then say the method wants a argument in the parameter thats of Type X, I declare type X and pass it in. Methods often have overloads, meaning that they can work with different parameters, so pressing up/down to scroll through them is also helpful in working out what is the most convenient in your situation. When you are passing in arguments to a method (in its parameter) type comma to refresh the tooltip indicating each arguments datatype.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```
myRichTextBox.Lines = myList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
richTextBox1.Lines = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using linq `Aggregate` which applies an accumulator function over a sequence.

```
richTextBoxResults.Text = listStrSessionIdLines.Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);
```